# How to run ngrok in background?

Tags: terminal, ngrok

I tried running ngrok in the background with following command:

```
./ngrok -subdomain test -config=ngrok.cfg 80 &
```

the process is running:

```
[1] 3866
```

and the subdomain doesn't work.

It works with:

```
./ngrok -subdomain test -config=ngrok.cfg 80
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

as explained [here](https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/issues/57)

```
ngrok -log=stdout 80 > /dev/null &
```

Comment: Does not work for ngrok2.  Any ideas for the new version?

Comment: @toas939 Oh, thanks man! Too much answers, and none of them is correct.

Comment: If you want to run this in a production environment and without having to open up your terminal, you can create and run ngrok as a service that will automatically start when your machine boots. Check here for instructions. https://ngrok.com/docs/ngrok-link#service

Comment: @dave4jr: Is ngrok-link included in the ngrok client or does one have to install something else? The service command isn't recognized by ngrok

Comment: @AndyFaizan Unfortunately it does cost a little extra, I forget how much our company paid for this but I don't remember it being a lot.

Comment: Okay. I asked because I already have a paid account but it still didn't work. Well, thanks anyway.

Comment: I want to ngrok a folder into the background... how can I do this? `./ngrok http file:///my-folder -log=stdout http > /dev/null &` doesn't work :(

Comment: How can I get obtain its output?

Comment: As of version 2.0.24, ngrok http 80 --log=stdout > ngrok.log & did the trick.

Answer (score 48):

as described previously you can run ngrok in background with

```
./ngrok http 8080 > /dev/null &
```

next you can use curl and for example `jq` a command-line JSON processor.

```
export WEBHOOK_URL="$(curl http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels | jq ".tunnels[0].public_url")"
```

your URL will be accessible from $WEBHOOK_URL env variable and you can use it anywhere.

Comment: This is by far the best solution for programatically accessing it!

Comment: did you check it?

Comment: I might suggest `curl --silent` (or `curl -s`) and `jq -r` to have quieter output.  So: `$(curl -s http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels | jq -r '.tunnels[0].public_url')` inside the double quotes.  (Feel free to pull this into the answer; leaving it as a comment for now.)

Comment: This is not deterministic if you have more than one tunnel. A simple workaround is to force just one tunnel by using only HTTPS: `ngrok http --bind-tls=true --log=stdout 8080 > /dev/null &`

Comment: `jq: error: Could not open file .tunnels[0].public_url: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 23):

Easy: `ngrok http 80 --log=stdout > ngrok.log &` did the trick.

Comment: `nohup ngrok http 80 --log=stdout > ngrok.log &` seems like safer in case ssh connection is dead

Comment: In 2024, top 2 answers did not work. Only this one did.

Answer (score 16):

Visit http://localhost:4040/status on your local machine, or see more here: [View random ngrok URL when run in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322988/view-random-ngrok-url-when-run-in-background).

Comment: Or sign up for a free account on the ngrok site and connect your local install to it - then you can view your active tunnels online.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a little bash script I wrote which runs `ngrok` in the background.  It then tries to sets a `NGROK_PUBLIC_URL` variable by calling a `curl` command (against http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnels) followed by a `sed` command (which extracts the ngrok public URL).  This all runs inside a loop until `NGROK_PUBLIC_URL` has a valid value as it normally takes ngrok 2 or 3 seconds for it's tunnels to become established.

### `start-ngrok.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

# Set local port from command line arg or default to 8080
LOCAL_PORT=${1-8080}

echo "Start ngrok in background on port [ $LOCAL_PORT ]"
nohup ngrok http ${LOCAL_PORT} &>/dev/null &

echo -n "Extracting ngrok public url ."
NGROK_PUBLIC_URL=""
while [ -z "$NGROK_PUBLIC_URL" ]; do
  # Run 'curl' against ngrok API and extract public (using 'sed' command)
  export NGROK_PUBLIC_URL=$(curl --silent --max-time 10 --connect-timeout 5 \
                            --show-error http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnels | \
                            sed -nE 's/.*public_url":"https:..([^"]*).*/\1/p')
  sleep 1
  echo -n "."
done

echo
echo "NGROK_PUBLIC_URL => [ $NGROK_PUBLIC_URL ]"
```

The script takes a port as an optional command line argument i.e.

```
$ . start-ngrok.sh 1234

Run NGROK in background on port [ 1234 ]
Extracting ngrok public url ...
NGROK_PUBLIC_URL => [ 75d5faad.ngrok.io ]
```

... but will run on port `8080` if the port isn't supplied ...

```
$ . start-ngrok.sh 

Run NGROK in background on port [ 8080 ]
Extracting ngrok public url ...
NGROK_PUBLIC_URL => [ 07e7a373.ngrok.io ]
```

The `NGROK_PUBLIC_URL` now contains the public url i.e.

```
$ echo $NGROK_PUBLIC_URL
07e7a373.ngrok.io
```

This can be accessed / used in your applications.

> **Note:** This script needs to be *sourced* (`. start-ngrok.sh` OR `source start-ngrok.sh`). This is because it is setting an environment variable which wont be available if run normally in a new shell (i.e. `./start-ngrok.sh`). See https://superuser.com/q/176783 for more info.

You can also create a little script using `pkill` / `kill` etc to stop the background `ngrok` process: -

### `stop-ngrok.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Stopping background ngrok process"
kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep 'ngrok' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2}')
echo "ngrok stopped"
```

Comment: but this still does not run in the background. It kills when i close the terminal

Comment: It doesn't on mine - that's what the `nohup` (no hangup) command does - `nohup ngrok http ${LOCAL_PORT} &>/dev/null &` - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup for more details.

Comment: To kill the proces you could have issued a simple: `kill -9 "$(pgrep ngrok)"`

Comment: Very nice, never used `pgrep` before, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 11):

In Ngrok 2, -log is neither necessary nor available (though you can control log levels in the configuration file). `ngrok > /dev/null &` is sufficient.

Comment: But how do I know the URL to access my service?

Comment: If you want to do that, you'll have to run it in the foreground (AFAIK). Background running is primarily helpful for running as a service, when you'd more than likely know your domain.

Comment: See my answer, there is a way.

Comment: Also Artem's answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48841928/313756 (with a comment from me to slightly modify it.)

Comment: @Oliv: The easiest way of checking the URL is to log in into the Ngrok web page and using the Dashboard.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use multiple shell windows or run any service in the background from a single SSH session that the simplest way is to use [screen](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/#install).

To install on the Centos Linux use `yum install screen`

Then start like any other command `screen`, after that type `ngrok` command within a parameters.

Detaching is the most powerful part of screen.  Screen allows you to detach from a window and reattach later.

If your network connection fails, screen will automatically detach your session!
You can detach from the window using “**Ctrl-a**” “**D**”.

This will drop you back into your shell.

All screen windows are still there and you can re-attach to them later using `screen -r`

Comment: It is generally considered a bad answer if you can't use your answer without the link.

Answer (score 7):

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnels
```

and you will see the public_url infomation  .

Here's example . 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0905.png

Answer (score 6):

Run `./ngrok http 5000 > /dev/null &` then `curl localhost:4040/status` to check url

Comment: need correction , nohup ./ngrok http 5000 > /dev/null &  so when we close terminal. process will not get kill

Comment: but this still does not run in the background

Comment: @Poonam Sorry I didn't put it in my answer. But please check out the `nohup` suggestion as the above comment says.

Answer (score 6):

Run  **./ngrok http (port number) &**
This runs the ngrok tunnel as a background process.
Ngrok usually opens a windown showing the assigned URL but since we are using the nohup command this is not visible.

Thus, then run **curl http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnels**
too see the URL assigned by ngrok

Comment: updated before, but no longer works. Failed to connect to localhost port 4040: Connection refused.
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48841928/5766054 answer

Comment: but this still does not run in the background. It kills when i close the terminal

Answer (score 6):

so i tried everything but the best answer to this which works in the year 2020 is:

how to create public local host(8080):

```
ngrok -log=stdout 80 > ngrok.log &
```

then

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnels
```

Comment: Can confirm, best answer for 2020.

Comment: doesn't work with ngrok==2.3.35 `Incorrect Usage: flag provided but not defined: -log`

Comment: use `ngrok --log=stdout 80 > ngrok.log &` instead

Answer (score 5):

try to run as service. and check it from ngrok website.
 I tried for ngrok version 2.2.8 on a Raspberry pi 3.

ngrok.service as

```
[Unit]
Description=Share local port(s) with ngrok
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1min
StandardOutput=null
StandardError=null
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/ngrok start --log /var/log/ngrok.log --config /etc/ngrok.yml --all
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall ngrok

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

configuration file: ngrok.yml
    authtoken:

```
tunnels:
  <your Tunel Name >:
    proto: http
    addr: 80
```

Answer (score 4):

Use below script for ngrok2

```
nohup ngrok http 3000 &
```

This will write logs to file nohup.out

Comment: nohup.out will not then contain sufficient information to know the API tunnel in use. See Hemanth's response.

Answer (score 2):

nohup ./ngrok http 80 &

Hit localhost:4040 to get the public URL assigned by ngrok

Answer (score 1):

You can use **screen** for that. Here is an example of how I use it:

> screen -d -m ~/./ngrok http test.cc:8080

Answer (score 1):

Ngrok now has its own solution for it, which is "installing as a service."

This will start the service on machine boot and restart the service automatically in case of any failure. There is an official document that explains it precisely: https://ngrok.com/docs/secure-tunnels/ngrok-agent/installing-as-a-service/

Answer (score 0):

```
nohup /usr/local/bin/ngrok --config /etc/ngrok.yml http 8080 &
```

If you link with ngrok account, then you can view the public url in ngrok site, do not need to curl the local url
Public url https://dashboard.ngrok.com/status

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cotunnel](https://www.cotunnel.com). It is ngrok alternative. The cotunnel installation script creates service and works itself on the background.

Comment: I think is kinda too much to say it's an alternative... It tries to be but it's way too far away from ngrok as in the flexibility. Plus, honestly, I don't like the ideea that someone is able to ssh into my server without any user/pass directly from their site. From a security perspective, this sucks big time! Installed, checked, uninstalled. Period!

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is using the [ngrok npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrok). If you have Node installed, you can run ngrok and print out the URL as shown below:

```js
require('ngrok').connect({ proto: 'http', port: 3000 }).then(url => {
  console.log(url);
});
```

Not strictly running it in the background, but I find this to be the easiest approach for my requirements: starting ngrok and a web server that's aware of its ngrok url in a single command.

Answer (score 0):

```
./ngrok http 80 -log=stdout > /dev/null &
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - to me, this looks like a duplicate of the existing answers

Answer (score 0):

In **Windows Batch Script (.bat)**, if you want to execute next command without waiting ngrok, use the following command with **start /b**:

```
start /b ngrok http 80 --log=stdout > ngrok.log &
```

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

1. First set **console_ui** to **false** in your config file (.ngrok2/ngrok.yml)
2. Run command like this

   ```
   $ ./ngrok start demo &
   ```

Extra: if you started this via ssh and you want it to continue running even if you disconnect run it like this

```
nohup ./ngrok start demo &
```

Example of my config file

```
    authtoken: XXXXX
    region: us
    console_ui: false
    web_addr: localhost:4040


    tunnels:    
      demo:
        proto: http
        addr: 9090
        hostname: demo.mysite.com
        inspect: false
        auth: "demo:secret"
```