# View random ngrok URL when run in background

Tags: ngrok

When I start an ngrok client with `./ngrok tcp 22` it runs in the foreground and I can see the randomly generated forwarding URL, such as `tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:12345 -> localhost:22`.

If I run in it the background with `./ngrok tcp &`, I can't find any way to see the forwarding URL. How can I run ngrok in the background and still see the URL?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There are a couple of ways.

You can either:

1) Visit `localhost:4040/status` in your browser to see a bunch of information, or

2) Use curl to hit the API: `localhost:4040/api/tunnels`

Answer (score 27):

If you want to get the first tunnel then `jq` will be your friend:

```
curl -s localhost:4040/api/tunnels | jq -r '.tunnels[0].public_url'
```

When running more than one instance of ngrok then use the tunnel name `/api/tunnels/:name`.

Comment: In zsh for some reason, I had to prefix the '[' and ']' with '\', so here I had to run `curl -s localhost:4040/api/tunnels | jq -r .tunnels\[0\].public_url`. But works perfectly, thank!

Comment: @HenriqueBruno for portability you can use double-quotes: `curl -s localhost:4040/api/tunnels | jq -r ".tunnels[0].public_url"`

Comment: True! Haven't thought about it. Thanks!

Comment: @François Leblanc Thanks！

Comment: Or if you don't want to install jq: #!/bin/bash

ngrok_output=$(curl --silent --show-error http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnels)

# Find which subdomain ngrok assigned:
ngrokUrl=$(echo $ngrok_output | sed -nE 's/.*public_url":"https:..([^"]*).*/\1/p')

Answer (score 19):

This little Python (2.7) script will call the ngrok API and print the current  URL's:

```
import json
import os 

os.system("curl  http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels > tunnels.json")

with open('tunnels.json') as data_file:    
    datajson = json.load(data_file)


msg = "ngrok URL's: \n'
for i in datajson['tunnels']:
  msg = msg + i['public_url'] +'\n'

print (msg)
```

Comment: how can I do it with python3 with only urllib.urlopen? I don't want to 1. call the external command curl, 2. redirect to a file..Thanks

Comment: Why should you use curl (system dependant) and save it on a json file while you could just make an http request?

Answer (score 5):

Run ./ngrok http  & This runs the ngrok tunnel as a background process. Ngrok usually opens a window showing the assigned URL but since we are using the nohup command this is not visible.

Thus, then run **`curl http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnels`** too see the URL assigned by ngrok

Answer (score 4):

If it helps anyone I wrote a quick script to extract the generated random url in Node:

It makes assumption you're only interested in the secure url.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
fetch('http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => json.tunnels.find(tunnel => tunnel.proto === 'https'))
  .then(secureTunnel => console.log(secureTunnel.public_url))
  .catch(err => {
    if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
      return console.error("Looks like you're not running ngrok.")
    }
    console.error(err)
  })
```

If you wanted all tunnels:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
fetch('http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => json.tunnels.map(tunnel => tunnel.public_url))
  .then(publicUrls => publicUrls.forEach(url => console.log(url)))
  .catch(err => {
    if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
      return console.error(
        "Looks like you're not running ngrok."
      )
    }
    console.error(err)
  })
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import json
import requests


def get_ngrok_url():
    url = "http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels/"
    res = requests.get(url)
    res_unicode = res.content.decode("utf-8")
    res_json = json.loads(res_unicode)
    for i in res_json["tunnels"]:
        if i['name'] == 'command_line':
            return i['public_url']
            break
```

This is an edit of JUN_NETWORKS python 3 code. It outputs the HTTPS URL only. I find Ngrok will randomly change the order of which is URL is displayed first sometimes outputting HTTP. The additional loop will consistently look for the 'tunnel' named 'command_line' which is the HTTPS URL.

Answer (score 4):

Use the ngrok API to get all active URLs

You will need to generate a token first (https://dashboard.ngrok.com/api)

Then fetch the active endpoints from the API

```
curl \
-H "Authorization: Bearer {API_KEY}" \
-H "Ngrok-Version: 2" \
https://api.ngrok.com/endpoints
```

check documentation: https://ngrok.com/docs/api/resources/endpoints

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way for me to check random generated URL is to go to [ngrok official site > dashboard > endpoints > status](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/endpoints/status) and check the URLs and status of my endpoints

PS: A comment was created when there was no documentation to fetch those endpoints via API. I described it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74403327/11280067)

Comment: That way the URL can't be used with programs and scripts. What if some program needs to access the ngrok URL or if you need the web page to be automatically updated with the correct link?

Comment: ngrok also provides API to check endpoints

I described it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74403327/11280067

Answer (score 2):

In Python3

```
import json
import requests


def get_ngrok_url():
    url = "http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels"
    res = requests.get(url)
    res_unicode = res.content.decode("utf-8")
    res_json = json.loads(res_unicode)
    return res_json["tunnels"][0]["public_url"]
```

This returned json have 2 url for **http** and **https**.
If you want only **https url**, you `res_json["tunnels"][index num]["proto"]`

Answer (score 2):

If you love PowerShell, here it is in variables.

```bsh
$ngrokOutput = ConvertFrom-Json (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels).Content
$httpsUrl = $ngrokOutput.tunnels.public_url[0]
$httpUrl = $ngrokOutput.tunnels.public_url[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby

```rb
require 'httparty'

# get ngrok public url
begin
  response = HTTParty.get 'http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels'
  json = JSON.parse response.body
  new_sms_url = json['tunnels'].first['public_url']
rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
  print 'no ngrok instance found. shutting down'
  exit
end
```

Answer (score 0):

#### A Node.js solution.

**Bonus**: It copies the url to the clipboard in Windows, Mac and Linux<sup>1</sup>

```js
const http = require("http");
const { execSync } = require("child_process");

const callback = (res) => {
    let data = "";
    res.on("data", (chunk) => (data += chunk));
    res.on("end", () => {
        const resJSON = JSON.parse(data);
        const tunnels = resJSON.tunnels;

        const { public_url: url } = tunnels.find(({ proto }) => proto === "https");

        console.log(url);

        // Copy to clipboard
        switch (process.platform) {
            case "win32":
                execSync(`echo ${url} | clip`);
                break;
            
            case "darwin":
                execSync(`echo ${url} | pbcopy`);
                break;
                
            case "linux":
                // NOTE: this requires xclip to be installed
                execSync(`echo ${url} | xclip -selection clipboard`);
                break;
                
            default:
                break;
        }
    });
};

http.get("http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels", callback);
```

[1] You need to install `xclip` first:

```sh
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using nodejs I did this

```js
const getURL = async () => {
  // inspect if the callback is working at: http://127.0.0.1:4040/inspect/http 
  const ngrok = await import('ngrok')
  const api = ngrok.getApi();
  const { tunnels } = JSON.parse(await api?.get('api/tunnels') ?? '{}')
  // if we already have a tunnel open, disconnect. We're only allowed to have 4
  if (tunnels?.length > 0) await ngrok.disconnect()
  return await ngrok.connect(3000)
}
```

Comment: use 
const tunnels = await api.listTunnels();
instead of
api.get
as its deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C# solution that fetches first URL from [ngrok Agent API](https://ngrok.com/docs/ngrok-agent/api/) provided by `localhost:4040/api`.

```cs
//fetch xml from API `api/tunnels/command_line`
using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, 
    "http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels/command_line");
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept.ToString(), "application/xml");
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

//parse and get the first PublicURL element's text
const string Xpath = "/tunnelResource/PublicURL";
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(content);
var xmlNode = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode(Xpath);
var xmlElement = xmlNode as XmlElement;
var url = xmlElement.InnerText;
```

Answer (score -1):

May be I'm a little too late in answering but would be glad if it is helpful for anyone visiting the question.

***Above answers are solutions to see/check the redirection URL. However to run ngrok in background, you could try using screen in linux . Incase you need help here a quick [reference](https://uisapp2.iu.edu/confluence-prd/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=115540034)

Steps:
1. Just run the ngrok in screen and then detach.
2. Use the python script given by Gerard above to see the URL.

I have followed the same process and it works!

Answer (score -1):

There is a better way to do that just login to your account on ngrok.com.
Your URL will be in your dashboard.